# Pass json parameters into webapi from Power BI

Tags: web-services, powerbi

I have some questions in Power BI for calling a web api.

1. I want to pass json parameters into my webapi as a post request from power BI.

   For example:

   ```
   url = http://localhost:56661/api
   json = {"id":1,"name":"api","data":"this is for testing"}
   ```

   And parse the json response received from the API and display the results in the dashboad.
2. Is there any way i can give the user an input for taking the json parameters dynamically or let the user edit the parameters passed in the dashboard?
3. I am able to call the api and get the response through execute R script. But i would like to give user the ability to edit json the parameters.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Grandizer, i wrote an R script to make an API call. Regarding points 2 & 3 , i used `Manage parameters` option to enter and edit json parameters. However , i couldn't find a direct/easy way to achieve this.